# Tomcat Deployment

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, ant, webserver, tomcat7

I am very new to tomcat, 
and I currently using tomcat 7.
I have deployment issues related to it.
I am getting "HTTP Status 404" error when i invoke the application.

The Problem description is as follows:

I have Eclipse Helios IDE.
I have Configured it to Tomcat 7, and i have started the server which gave me ***no error***.

```
Jul 10, 2012 11:33:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;.;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/lib/i386;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin
Jul 10, 2012 11:33:20 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8090"]
Jul 10, 2012 11:33:20 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 10, 2012 11:33:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1034 ms
Jul 10, 2012 11:33:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 10, 2012 11:33:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.28
Jul 10, 2012 11:33:21 AM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [172] milliseconds.
Jul 10, 2012 11:33:21 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8090"]
Jul 10, 2012 11:33:21 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 10, 2012 11:33:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 725 ms
```

I am using a ant build file to deploy it to the current location:

```
C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.28-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.28\webapps
```

My build.properties file is as follows.

```
deploydir=C:/apache-tomcat-7.0.28-windows-x86/apache-tomcat-7.0.28/webapps
userlib=C:/Jar/employee
<!--userlib=C:/Jar/basicstruts2jars-->
warname=balaji
```

After starting the server, and building using ant build the **build was successful**.
a file by name "balaji.war" got created in webapps folder.

I have changed the port number to 8090 in "server.xml".

My Project structure just one index.html file in html folder (public property).

[image: Project Structre]

When i run the url: `http://localhost:8090/balaji/html/index.html`

i am getting 404 error, as follows :

[image: Error 404]

The war file is exactly on the same location (as you can see in the below picture) and the server is started, but still the problem persists.

[image: war file location]

Please help me resolve this deployment issue.

Comment: In the server logs, i didn't see that the context balaji has been loaded by your server, did you restart your server after deploying the war?

Comment: yes i restarted and tried it again..!
Still it dint work.
It is not deploying...!
Please help me find a solution...

Comment: If you go to _C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.28-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.28\webapps_ can you see the the file balaji.war?

Comment: Yes, And i have posted that with a picture too..
In the last Picture you can see 'balaji.war' in the desired location...!

Comment: i can't see the picture! did you check the log files (e.g. tomcat/logs/catalina.out) for problems with deployment?

Comment: @m.abbas : the folder you mentioned is empty even after doing the deployment after starting the server..
The program runs if i run on server.
But not using a ANT file or deploying the war file.
The ant file was working fine with JBoss or weblogic.
But in Tomcat war file is getting created but i am not able run it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want tomcat to deploy your war at start up two properties **unpackWARs** & **autoDeploy** need to set to **true** in `server.xml` located in

> tomcat-home/conf/server/xml.

Find for Host in server.xml and modify it to

```
<Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```